# ajax and codeigniter Post dataString and receive array

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this view where I collect a key named **MYVAR** in a form **contactForm**

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf" id="contactForm">
   <input name="MYVAR" type="text" placeholder="DO_IT..." required>
   <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" >  DO IT </button>
</form>
```

then in this view I have a script to send via ajax this key to controller as **dataString**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".btn_submit").click(function() {
    var MYVAR       = jQuery("input#MYVAR").val();
    var dataString  = 'MYVAR='+ MYVAR;
    alert(dataString);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/do_it/method/",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
            jQuery('#successMessage').html("<b><p style='color:#5b5b5b; float:left; margin-top:3px; padding-top:50px;'>success.</p></b><br/><br/>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
            jQuery('#successMessage');
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

In the controller `do_it` inside  **method**  i would read var **MYVAR**

```
function method()
{   
  //posted var
  $key = $this->input->post('MYVAR');
  $this->load->model('mine_model');
  //get data according key variable 
  $data['result'] = $this->mine_model->get( array('data' => $MYVAR));
  //encode it? 
  echo json_encode($data); 
  //$this->load->view('view',$data);
}
```

But Is not doing anything...

What am I missing?

Also I do not have any idea How to receive $data ['result'] in view with jQuery and then print it in view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some code that do it like you want:

My JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('#contactForm').submit(function() {
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type : 'post',
      url  : '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/do_it/method/',
      data : dataString,
      dataType : 'json',
      success : function(res) {
        console.log(res); // to see the object
        // your code here
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

My PHP (CodeIgniter)

```
function method() { 
  $key = $this->input->post('MYVAR');
  $this->load->model('mine_model');
  $data['result'] = $this->mine_model->get( array('data' => $MYVAR));

  // set text compatible IE7, IE8
  header('Content-type: text/plain'); 
  // set json non IE
  header('Content-type: application/json'); 

  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: OH,, I forgot something: you don't need to verify the browser to output header on PHP.. if you set just "text/plain" works fine for every browser.. I've tested.. ;)

Comment: How can I print result if is an array? `jQuery('#successMessage').html("<b><p style='color:#5b5b5b; float:left; margin-top:3px; padding-top:50px;'>success.</p></b><br/><br/>")`

Comment: do you want an array back from PHP ?? ou just HTML ?
if is an array you care about an object `echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Success'));` and than in you JS: `$('#successMessage').html(res.message);`

Comment: yes, the result I get from model is an array, this I want to print it, If I would not be using ajas I will only write: `foreach ($result  as $val):   ?>
<h2><? echo "ID: " . $val['1st']; ?> </h2>
<h3><? echo "IDW: " . $val['2nd'] ?></h3>
<?endforeach ; ?>`

Comment: I use `if ($this->input->is_ajax_request() {` by CodeIgniter to verify ajax or not, by this condition I print an array (to ajax) or a HTML (normal request)

Answer (score 1):

Once try this code

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(".btn_submit").click(function() {
        alert(jQuery("input#MYVAR").val());
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/do_it/method/",
            data: {MYVAR:jQuery("input#MYVAR").val()},
            success: function() {
                jQuery('#successMessage').html("<b><p style='color:#5b5b5b; float:left; margin-top:3px; padding-top:50px;'>success.</p></b><br/><br/>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                jQuery('#successMessage');
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

In controller just send the data like this**(You have already done)**

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=> 'true', 'data' => array(1,2,3)))
```

But in your in view `success()` needs to be changed to `success(response)`

You can use the `json` result like this

```
success: function(response) {
    if(response.status){
        jQuery('#successMessage').html("<b><p style='color:#5b5b5b; float:left; margin-top:3px; padding-top:50px;'>success.</p></b><br/><br/>")
        .hide()
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {
        jQuery('#successMessage');
        });

        //response.data[0] gives 1
        //response.data[1] gives 2
        //response.data[2] gives 3
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble, could you please post all code?, Maybe I am still missing something as after writing "1" and then clicking button the following appears in url    `index.php/do_it?MYVAR=1`